# ThreadPoolExecutor and the queue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

I thought that using [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) we can submit `Runnable`s to be executed either in the `BlockingQueue` passed in the constructor or using the `execute` method.
Also my understanding was that if a task is available it will be executed.
What I don't understand is the following:

```
public class MyThreadPoolExecutor {  

    private static ThreadPoolExecutor executor;  

    public MyThreadPoolExecutor(int min, int max, int idleTime, BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue){  
        executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(min, max, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES, queue);   
        //executor.prestartAllCoreThreads();  
    }  

    public static void main(String[] main){
        BlockingQueue<Runnable> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
        final String[] names = {"A","B","C","D","E","F"};  
        for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){  
            final int j = i;  
            q.add(new Runnable() {  

                @Override  
                public void run() {  
                    System.out.println("Hi "+ names[j]);  

                }  
            });         
        }  
        new MyThreadPoolExecutor(10, 20, 1, q);   
        try {  
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);  
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        /*executor.execute(new Runnable() {  

            @Override  
            public void run() {  

                System.out.println("++++++++++++++");  

            }   
        });  */
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){  
            final int j = i;  
            q.add(new Runnable() {   

                @Override  
                public void run() {  
                    System.out.println("Hi "+ j);  

                }  
            });  
        }   


    }  


}
```

This code does not do absolutely anything unless I either uncomment the `executor.prestartAllCoreThreads();` in the constructor OR I call `execute` of the runnable that prints `System.out.println("++++++++++++++");` (it is also commented out).

Why?
Quote (my emphasis):

> By default, even core threads are initially created and **started only
>   when new tasks arrive**, but this can be overridden dynamically using
>   method prestartCoreThread() or prestartAllCoreThreads(). You probably
>   want to prestart threads if you construct the pool with a non-empty
>   queue.

Ok. So my queue is not empty. But I create the `executor`, I do `sleep` and then I add new `Runnable`s to the queue (in the loop to 100).
Doesn't this loop count as `new tasks arrive`?
Why doesn't it work and I have to either `prestart` or explicitely call `execute`?

Comment: Worker threads are spawned as tasks arrive by `execute`, and these are the ones that interact with the underlying work queue. You need to prestart the workers if you begin with a non-empty work queue. See the [implementation in OpenJDK 7](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java).

Comment: @veer:Yes I know. But I start with an non-empty queue and then start adding to the queue. Why do I need to prestart the workers?Why should I need to look into the implementation each time? Either the specification is wrong or I fail to understand it. So which is it?

Comment: Again, the workers are the ones that directly interact with the queue. They are only spawned on demand when passed via `execute` (or the layers above it, e.g. `invokeAll`, `submit`, etc.). See the code for `execute` [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#1300).

Comment: @veer:When I prestart the workers, the code works without ever calling `execute`

Comment: Yes, that is because __the workers have already been started__ and thus __they are able to check the queue for available work__.

Comment: "I thought that using ThreadPoolExecutor we can submit Runnables to be executed either in the BlockingQueue passed in the constructor or using the execute method."  This is wrong, after creating the thread pool you should only submit new tasks using the execute method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Worker threads are spawned as tasks arrive by execute, and these are the ones that interact with the underlying work queue. You need to prestart the workers if you begin with a non-empty work queue. See the [implementation in OpenJDK 7](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java).

I repeat, **the workers are the ones that interact with the work queue**. They are only spawned on demand when passed via `execute`. (or the layers above it, e.g. `invokeAll`, `submit`, etc.) If they are not started, it will not matter how much work you add to the queue, since there is nothing checking it as **there are no workers started**.

`ThreadPoolExecutor` does not spawn worker threads until necessary or if you pre-empt their creation by the methods [prestartAllCoreThreads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#prestartAllCoreThreads%28%29) and [prestartCoreThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#prestartCoreThread%28%29). If there are no workers started, then there is no way any of the work in your queue is going to be done.

The reason adding an initial `execute` works is that it forces the creation of a **sole** core worker thread, which then can begin processing the work from your queue. You could also call `prestartCoreThread` and receive similar behavior. If you want to start *all* the workers, you must call `prestartAllCoreThreads` or submit that number of tasks via `execute`.

See the code for `execute` below.

```
/**
 * Executes the given task sometime in the future.  The task
 * may execute in a new thread or in an existing pooled thread.
 *
 * If the task cannot be submitted for execution, either because this
 * executor has been shutdown or because its capacity has been reached,
 * the task is handled by the current {@code RejectedExecutionHandler}.
 *
 * @param command the task to execute
 * @throws RejectedExecutionException at discretion of
 *         {@code RejectedExecutionHandler}, if the task
 *         cannot be accepted for execution
 * @throws NullPointerException if {@code command} is null
 */
public void execute(Runnable command) {
    if (command == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    /*
     * Proceed in 3 steps:
     *
     * 1. If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, try to
     * start a new thread with the given command as its first
     * task.  The call to addWorker atomically checks runState and
     * workerCount, and so prevents false alarms that would add
     * threads when it shouldn't, by returning false.
     *
     * 2. If a task can be successfully queued, then we still need
     * to double-check whether we should have added a thread
     * (because existing ones died since last checking) or that
     * the pool shut down since entry into this method. So we
     * recheck state and if necessary roll back the enqueuing if
     * stopped, or start a new thread if there are none.
     *
     * 3. If we cannot queue task, then we try to add a new
     * thread.  If it fails, we know we are shut down or saturated
     * and so reject the task.
     */
    int c = ctl.get();
    if (workerCountOf(c) < corePoolSize) {
        if (addWorker(command, true))
            return;
        c = ctl.get();
    }
    if (isRunning(c) && workQueue.offer(command)) {
        int recheck = ctl.get();
        if (! isRunning(recheck) && remove(command))
            reject(command);
        else if (workerCountOf(recheck) == 0)
            addWorker(null, false);
    }
    else if (!addWorker(command, false))
        reject(command);
}
```

Comment: You are not answering the OP which is about the specification.And you answer by putting the implementation details of `one` of the JVM implementation (could be different for Oracle or IBM etc)

Comment: `Worker threads are spawned as tasks arrive by execute`. Also if the worker threads are started I can add tasks to the queue directly without needing to call `execute`

Comment: I very knowingly put the implementation details of one implementation (which is actually the _same_ as the one from the Oracle JDK). The OP is why the code works as it does, and I explained it. `ThreadPoolExecutor` does not spawn worker threads until necessary or if you pre-empt their creation by the methods [prestartAllCoreThreads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#prestartAllCoreThreads()) and [prestartCoreThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#prestartCoreThread()).

Comment: If you add work to the queue after calling `execute` once and it works, then you have successfully spawned a _single_ worker thread which is __alone__ in processing the work queue.

Comment: PPS OpenJDK is _not_ a JVM implementation.

Comment: So we are not supposed to interact with the worker threads via the `queue`?I mean the tasks should be added to the `queue` only via `execute` or it is also ok to add to the `queue` directly?

Comment: You can interact via the queue so long as you have worker threads waiting to consume work, hence why the documentation suggests you pre-start them for a non-empty work queue. "Priming" the executor by calling `execute` once will only start one worker, i.e. not the entire pool.

Answer (score 5):

A BlockingQueue is not a magic thread dispatcher. If you submit Runnable objects to the queue and there are no running threads to consume those tasks, they of course will not be executed. The execute method on the other hand will automatically dispatch threads according to the thread pool configuration if it needs to. If you pre-start all of the core threads, there will be threads there to consume tasks from the queue.