# Manage queue/workers of Thread pool in java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpoolexecutor

I want to manage my thread pool workers. Like if a queue has 5 workers then any how I will manage those workers. Suppose first worker should run after 4th worker or after some sorting of workers.

I am using ThreadPoolExecutor in my application. It is working as expected but need to manage those workers so my application will run as I sort those worker.
Please give me some hints or references.

Answer (score 2):

You should not attempt to manage the workers. You need to manage the queue.

See [ThreadPoolExecutor and the queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820120/threadpoolexecutor-and-the-queue) for a good introduction.

Answer (score 0):

The point of using a thread pool is to abstract away the management of threads from your application. If you need to manage the threads yourself, you're basically stating that you want to write your own thread pool.
In that case, using an Executor won't help, since you lose that level of control.
Instead, you might need to create and manage the threads yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can either manage the threads yourself or use concurrency primitives such as barriers, semaphores and so on in order to control the order. Check the java.util.concurrent package. For example the first worker can wait on a semaphore or countdownlatch that the other workers release at some point.